# asp.net send email using gmail on local machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using gmail in my asp.net site to send email. It is working fine on shared server but it donot send email when I run my site on local machine in visual studio. Please guide what should I do to make it sending emails from local machine as well.

thanks

below is my code:

```
 dt = systemrep.GetSystemInfo();
                dr = dt.Rows[0];
                From = dr["nm_EmailFrom"].ToString();
                SMTP = dr["nm_SMTP"].ToString();
                Port = dr["amt_Port"].ToString();
                EmailId = dr["nm_emailUserId"].ToString();
                EmailPassword = dr["nm_emailPassword"].ToString();
                DefaultCredations = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ind_Credentials"].ToString());
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential(EmailId, EmailPassword);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress(email.To));
                message.From = new MailAddress(From);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Subject = email.Subject;
                message.Body = email.Message;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = DefaultCredations;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Host = SMTP;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailId, EmailPassword);


                smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?  (Just enough to reproduce the problem, of course.)

Comment: What are the values for nm_SMTP, and amt_Port?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using as your SMTP server? If you are using `localhost` (which may work on the server), it probably won't work on your local machine.

Comment: I am sorry I am not aware of SMTP server. I just have IIS 5.1 on my machine, where and how I should set SMTP plz guide.

Comment: @haansi: if you are running XP (which it sounds like you are), you should probably point to Gmail's smtp server (smtp.gmail.com). What is the value of the variable `SMTP` that you posted?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending via smtp.gmail.com from your server OK, but the same code doesn't work on your local machine, it's probably a firewall or antivirus problem.

From your local machine, try "telnet smtp.gmail.com 25" and see if you can connect.

Try disabling the firewall and/or antivirus and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I couldn't understand telnet. I wrote telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 on command prompt and next there was written 220*******************************   plz guide